# Is it possible to use a laptop by multiple users remotely and independently?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, remote-desktop, remote-access

I have a laptop running windows 10 pro. Let's say I have administrator access I mean I am the admin/owner. I create a new profile for one of my friends. So, lets there are two profiles in my laptop: `Admin` and `Friend`. I want to give access the `Friend` profile to one of my friends remotely (via teamviewer/anydesk etc.). So, both of us can do our own works **independently at the same time** (myself from `Admin` profile, my friend from `Friend` profile). I searched a little bit and so far I understood that it's not possible. Most of the answers are 3-4 years old. So, I want to know that is there anything in 2020 which make it possible?

I don't know much about virtual machines either. If the first option is not possible via teamviewer/anydesk, would it be possible that I run the main OS and install a different OS (windows/Linux whatever needed) on the virtual box, giving access to that virtual box OS remotely (via teamviewer/anydesk etc), to my friend?

The goal would be that both of us can perform our own tasks independently as two users simultaneously.

Comment: On non-server Windows versions only one user can use the GUI at a time. A second user can be logged in (on Windows 10 pro via remote) but only one user can use the desktop and the applications.

Answer (score 1):

once I wanted to do something similar, I would think you can use this solution.
http://www.kimknight.net/remoteapptool

at the same time try to enable concurrent sessions in windows 10. On the internet there are many tutorials on how to achieve it easily, you just need a small program to achieve it.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I will check in details and give it a try.